# Laravel dropdown with current database value as placerholder

Tags: php, laravel-5, dropdown

I'm currently working on my laravel project and I have an issue I can't solve.
I want a dropdown-list filled with an specific amount of values out of a db table. But I want to have the placeholder as the current value from the database. Here is a impression how my current view looks like:

```
<option value="" selected hidden>Please select</option>
   @foreach($faculties as $faculty)
<option value="{{ Request::old('faculty') ? : $faculty->name }} ">
     {{ Request::old('faculty') ? : $faculty->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
```

The first option should be removed as soon I find out how to set the placeholder to the current db value.

My Controller looks like:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $course = Course::with('faculty')->findOrFail($id);

        $faculties = Faculty::where('active', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();

        return view('entities/course.edit', compact('course', 'faculties'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to use `lists` and send it to the view:

```
$faculties = Faculty::lists('name', 'id');

return view('nameoftheview.create', [
            'faculties' => $faculties,
            ]);
```

Then, in the view, you pass this variable to the select helper:

```
{!! Form::select('faculty', $faculties, old('faculty')) !!}
```

This will create a list with `id` as the value of the options and `name` as the text for each selection.

Answer (score 0):

Use Model Minding in form and set the third argument of select box `null`. Your form should look like this:

```
{!! Form::model($faculies,['action'=>['MyController@update',$course->id],'method'=>'patch']) !!}
    //Other html
    {!! Form::select('faculty', $faculties, null) !!}
    //Other html
{!! Form::close() !!}
```